# bootstrap tabs CSS box shadow on tab-content bottom not top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give tabs drop shadow using css.
But problem is top side which looks very ugly.

IS it possible to have

1. Drop shadow on bottom of tab-content only.
2. Top side must be transparent .. no white box thing as in example

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1746/

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="shadow">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
          <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
          <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"><br><br>Home</div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="profile"><br><br>Profile</div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="messages"><br><br>Message</div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="settings"><br><br>Settings</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why not add the shadow class to tab-content instead of the whole container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `shadow` class to `tab-content`

```
    <div class="tab-content shadow">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"><br><br>Home</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile"><br><br>Profile</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages"><br><br>Message</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="settings"><br><br>Settings</div>
    </div>
```

Check demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1751/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.77);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

When I am making shadows for CSS I always use the following site: [CSSMatic - Shadow Generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow). I was able to build what I think your looking for with the code above.